# Sound in Virtual Box cuts out

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-10.04, audio

I'm running Windows XP inside Virtual Box in Linux. In the beginning the sound works but after a while there's no more sound.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable pulse-audio and use only ALSA.

Comment: That's what I'm using.